running mstest using mono on linux
I have found similar questions, but nothing seems to work for me.
We have a mono environment set on linux by another team. This one unfortunately has no .net sdk inside it.
We try to migrate some .net projects there. The issue I am facing is that I can not seem to be able to generate or find mstest.exe or vstest.console.exe to be able to run the MStest unit tests.
From what I understood from previous answers on SO usually when adding the 2 nuget packages TestAdapter and TestFramework the mstest.exe should be inside the build folder (most likely) of TestAdapter. However, I cannot locate it there (only a couple of dlls exist).
When I execute 'find' on the root folder again nothing is returned, which makes me believe that it doesnt exist.
The same happened again when I was trying to bypass this by using vstest.console.exe. (that one is also nowhere to be found when I get Microsoft.TestPlatform from nuget.
Any idea on what I am doing wrong or possible misconceptions in my logic?
I thought of another 2 possible approaches:
1)Maybe install TestAgents and BuildTools? I would prefer though to find what is going wrong already now.
2)Maybe manipulate the dockerfile itself to include the sdk there? I do not have much experience there though.
This is a part of the yml file I am creating:
script:
    - msbuild src -restore -property:Configuration=Release
    
    # Install NuGet
    - wget -O nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe

# Restore MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework packages using NuGet
    - mono nuget.exe install MSTest.TestAdapter -Version 3.2.0 -OutputDirectory packages
    #- mono nuget.exe install Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost -Version 16.10.0 -OutputDirectory packages
    - mono nuget.exe install MSTest.TestFramework -Version 3.2.0 -OutputDirectory packages
    - msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release GetNewBuildType.Tests.csproj
    - mono nuget.exe restore GetNewBuildType.sln
    - dir /usr/bin
    #- dir /usr/local
    #- dir /opt
    - find ~ -iname "*mstest*.exe" 


https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-end-of-mono/ Unless you are ready to hack and maintain Mono on your own, you should migrate to .NET 8 and apply the specific steps for that platform.
